# How to set custom title attributes for UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitabbaritem

How i can set custom font for every UITabBarItem. All i found is [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:...] But it sets  the same attributes for all tabs.
I want to set attributes for every UITabBarItem and it must be custom. 
This method like [tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:forState:] doesn't work.

Comment: `[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:forState:]` successfully changes the text style for me. Are you saying you want each individual tab's text style to be different?

Comment: Yes. But your method doesn't work for me. I dont know why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051706/uitabbaritem-with-custom-title-color-and-images You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Use image if you want to accomplish this without that it is not possible 
read every UITabBarItem separately then use image for every one

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController=(UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;

UITabBar *tabBar=tabBarController.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *tabBarItemClassic=[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

UITabBarItem *tabBarItemAdvance=[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

UITabBarItem *tabBarItemMore=[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
```

now lets say i want to use different color for tabBarItemMore.

you can title to nil and can use custom designed image to be displayed there.

In my following case i am not using title i am using image which have title written below the icon.

```
[tabBarItemMore setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    [tabBarItemMore  setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```